# QPainter drawRect to existing image draws rounded edges instead of sharp edges. How to draw sharp edges?

Tags: qt, qpainter

My goal is to draw figures onto images and save to file. In this simplified example, I prepare an image for QPainter and then draw a rectangle via drawRect to the existing image and save to a file. The resultant image shows the combined image but the rectangle shows rounded edges instead of sharp edges. How to fix it? Your help is appreciated.

```
include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QPainter>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPen>
void paint_Object(QPainter *painter)
{
    QPen pen;
    pen.setWidth(40);
    pen.setColor(Qt::red);
    QRect rect;

    painter->setPen(pen);
    rect.setTopLeft(QPoint(100,100));
    rect.setWidth(100);
    rect.setHeight(200);
    painter->drawRect(rect);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString filename_in = "C:/Users/seany/VideoAd/temp/test.png";
    QString filename_out = "C:/Users/seany/VideoAd/temp/test_out.png";

    //Setup initial
    QImage test_image(filename_in);

    //Setup Painter with initial Image
    QPainter painter(&test_image);

    //Paint an overlaid image onto initial image
    paint_Object(&painter);

    //Write resultant image to file
    test_image.save(filename_out);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value for QPen join style is `Qt::BevelJoin`. That's way its coming round edges. Use `pen.setJoinStyle(Qt::MiterJoin)` for extended or sharp edges.
For more information read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html#setJoinStyle).

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @seany if that solution works, please accept or vote it so that others can easily find working solution to the same problem.